# Read entities of entity framework from frontend

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

Hello how can i access the entities generated by entity framework from front end?
from my business logic i can access it but i can't access it from frontend.

Can i move the entities from entity framework project to business logic layer or replicate them in it?

I think there should be an easy way to do it, because i can't belive microsoft has developed a pattern in whitch data layer should be referenced directly by ui, it is a thing people do when they are 8 years old

Comment: i don't know how to move enities, what i 've to do to move them?, it is exaclty what i have asked for

Comment: Nothing keeps you from displaying entities fetched by a context in a DataGridView, for instance. What is best for you depends on so many things you don't mention. Complexity, web/winforms/WPF/OData to name a few. Heck, maybe EF is not even the best option. Usually studying sample applications works better, e.g. [this one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. Lots of design work well having a DTO architecture and it is certainly possible using EF, though maybe easier using code first (see my answer below). Alternatively some like to proxy the data classes thus completely hiding the data implementation from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I will walk you through this from the Entity Framework 5 / VS2012 perspective. However other versions should work similarly.

Assuming from the above you have three projects (data/business/ui) and a entity framework context (.edmx) item in your data project.

1. Create a new project (class library) for your solution. This project will house your entity (POCO) objects so name it appropreatly.
2. Create a project reference from your data project to your new entities project
3. Create a new item in your new project (EF 5.x DbContextGenerator)
4. Delete the Context.tt file in the newly created item.
5. Open the other .tt file and modify the line that defines `inputFile` to map to your .edmx file

   `const string inputFile = @"../<dataprojectname>/<mydata>.edmx";`
6. In your data project expand out "mydata".edmx and locate the entities template named "mydata".tt (you will know it is the correct one because it expands to show a list of your entities) and delete it.
7. Modify the "mydata".Context.tt file: scroll down until you see the `using` statments. Append the list of usings with the namespace of your entities created in step 3.
8. Now you can create references from your business and UI projects directly to your entities project.

Hope this helps.